# Modifying an estimator in scikit-learn for use with CV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn and would like to use `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` to do cross-validation. I have a machine learning model where unphysical values are modified before scoring. For instance, if I use LASSO and get a vector of predicted values **y**, I will do something like `y[y<0]=0` before evaluating the success of the model. Is there a way I can incorporate this criterion in the estimator's `fit` function such that I can use sklearn's cross-validation function?

For instance, if I have

```py
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3)
```

I would like to be able to have all the predicted LASSO values to have a value of 0 if they were originally negative before doing `cross_validate`. Of course, I could just do the cross-validation myself and bypass this problem, but it'd be nice to use scikit-learn's built-in functions where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use custom scorers via `scoring` option provided in `cross_validate`. Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer
import numpy as np

def relu(x): return np.maximum(0, x)

def custom_error(y, y_pred):
    return mean_squared_error(relu(y), relu(y_pred))

scoring = make_scorer(custom_error, greater_is_better = False)
cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3, scoring = scoring)
```

The resulting errors will be negative (just negate them) because of `greater_is_better = False`. My example uses `mean_squared_error`. You can use other metrics, by defining how you calculate inside `custom_error` method. The one you were using by default was coefficient of determination, because it is [Lasso's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) default scoring function.

Comment: Thanks for this example! You stated "The resulting errors will be negative (just negate them) because of `greater_is_better = True`". Did you mean `greater_is_better = False`? If I understand it correctly, `mean_squared_error` produces a positive quantity. Therefore, we set `greater_is_better = False` to ensure a low (close to 0) MSE is good. Where does the "negative"  come in here?

Comment: Oh, yes. Probably, it's an internal implementation of sklearn, when you want to minimize something, it negates the error and tries to maximize it. Notion of "score" I guess.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're saying the result from `cross_validate` will be a negative MSE. That makes sense now. I incorrectly thought you meant that your `mean_squared_error` function itself produced negative values.